# TSQL to number an ordered set

Tags: t-sql

How can I number an ordered set (ordered by date time value) with incremental values 1 to 4 using T-SQL?  I'd like the results to look like the following.  Thanks in advance.

```
1/1/2011    1
1/2/2011    2
1/3/2011    3
1/4/2011    4
1/5/2011    1
1/6/2011    2
1/7/2011    3
1/8/2011    4
1/9/2011    1
1/10/2011   2
1/11/2011   3
1/12/2011   4
1/13/2011   1
1/14/2011   2
1/15/2011   3
1/16/2011   4
1/17/2011   1
1/18/2011   2
1/19/2011   3
1/20/2011   4
```

Comment: Off topic to this question but [your question here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6724/dropping-duplicateredundant-unique-constraint-from-filestream-table/9723#9723) got migrated and answered. You won't have received notification I think as you are not registered on [dba.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT MyDate, ((row_number() over (order by MyDate) - 1) % 4) + 1
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: /me shakes his fist at the slightly faster typist then hits the +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have the set of dates already in `SomeTable.dt`:

```
SELECT dt, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) - 1)  % 4 + 1 AS col2
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT date, ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) - 1) % 4) + 1 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option without row_number (will work also for SQL2k):

```
SELECT 
    D.DateValue, 
    (DATEPART(DD, D.DateValue) - 1) % 4 + 1 AS Col1,
    DATEDIFF(DD, '20110101', D.DateValue) % 4 + 1 AS Col2
FROM D
```

Here Col1 will start numeration with each new month, and Col2 will number records across all months. I.e., if you have more than a month selected, you will retrieve on the border of the month:

```
DateValue   Col1 Col2
2011-01-29  1    1
2011-01-30  2    2
2011-01-31  3    3
2011-02-01  1    4
2011-02-02  2    1
```